# User login using facebook Facebook login API

Tags: android

I have developed an app that uses Facebook login for user to login into the app.However i have to uninstall Facebook for android for it to work.Any assistance?
Below is the code.

```
public class MokoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView create_account;
    EditText name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        create_account=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_createAccount);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        create_account.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.textView_createAccount:
                String user_name=name.getText().toString();
                if(user_name.length()<4){
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MokoActivity.this,"Invalid Name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                else{
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true,new Session.StatusCallback(){
                public void call(Session session,SessionState state,Exception exception){
                    if(state.isOpened()){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MokoActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username",name.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
}
```

It works fine only that if facebook for android is installed,it doesnt redirect to HomeActivity intent after login.I have to uninstall facebook for android in order for it to function.

Comment: As i got your question, if you want to uninstall FB app from your android device then you can go to setting->apps/manage app/application->tap on FB app in list and uninstall it.

Comment: @mungaihkamau You mean to say, if default facebook application is installed on your device at that time your application is not working.

Comment: yes Dipak Keshariya.It redirects to the facebook login page,but after entering the username and password still remains on the login intent.

Comment: @mungaihkamau Are you using android facebook sdk?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya yes.i am using the facebook sdk

Comment: @mungaihkamau Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Update below code of your application, it will solve your problem and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

And see below link for more information on integrate Facebook in android application with complete source code.

[Facebook Integration - Android](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-update-facebook-status-via.html)

Comment: Here's my code.It works fine only that if facebook for android is installed it doesnt redirect to the HomePage activity after log in but stays on Moko Activity

Comment: @mungaihkamau Where is your code? and don't change complete code, only update above code of your application.

Comment: where exactly in my code do you want me to paste the code snippet you suggested above?